# Trim &nbsp; with PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a sentence like this.

```
1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2 &nbsp; &nbsp; 3 &nbsp; 4
```

As you see, in between 1 2 and 3 text, there are extra spaces. I want the output with only one space between them. so my output will be `1 2 3 4`.

If I use trim, it can only remove white space, but not that `&nbsp;` How can I use PHP trim function to get the output like this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$str = "1 $nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2 &nbsp; &nbsp; 3 &nbsp; 4";
$new_str = str_replace("&nbsp;", '', $str);
```

Comment: PHP code is interpreted on the server, not the client.  The browser never sees it.

Answer (score 61):

Found this at php.net, works great:

```
$myHTML = "&nbsp;abc"; 
$converted = strtr($myHTML, array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES))); 
trim($converted, chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0));
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php#98812

Comment: Did you notice missing parens?

Comment: @Deele I don't always test my code, but when I do, I do it in production.

Comment: Interesting that the browser actually shows you `&nbsp;` when the character was just `0xA0`. It took me your answer to realize that and fix my *bug*.

Comment: Can also be produced by typing `"\xC2\xA0"`.

Comment: It works also without second line. What is second line for?

Comment: The solution is wrong due the the way UTF-8 works. For example, it breaks on `"&nbsp;abà"`.

Comment: It also breaks on '«'

Answer (score 43):

A more inclusive answer for those who want to just do a trim:

```
$str = trim($str, " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xC2\xA0");
```

Same trim handling   html entities:

```
$str = trim(html_entity_decode($str), " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xC2\xA0");
```

This html_entity_decode and trim interaction is outlined in the PHP docs here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#refsect1-function.html-entity-decode-notes

Comment: This doesn't strip &nbsp; when it's just a 6-character string.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii: It not supposed to strip &nbsp; because thats an html entity and not appropriate for trim. If you want to trim off extra &nbsp; using html_entity_decode on the string first is the appropriate solution.

Comment: Note: This solution can possibly corrupt other characters at the start/end of the string, as trim() will look each byte individually!  E.g. `echo trim('´test´', " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xC2\xA0");` will corrupt the first character by deleting its first byte!

Comment: @Jay I assume maybe you are referring to multi-byte character corruption as each character in a standard PHP string is normally a byte? From what I understand trim() won't corrupt valid UTF8 character sequences, but it can corrupt invalid ones. A great discussion on this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066647/multibyte-trim-in-php

Comment: @Chaoix: I think we're talking about different things? You are referring to single-argument usage of `trim()` - which will only remove whitespaces. I was referring to two-argument usage of `trim()` with Unicode characters in the **second** argument of the function (a.k.a. `$characters`). That argument will be treated as individual bytes and potentially corrupt other characters while trimming.

Answer (score 11):

```
$str = "&nbsp;abc&nbsp;";

echo trim($str, "\xC2\xA0"); //abc
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: After many tests it's works for me, I suppose it depends of DB encoding...oh I really don't know why ^_^'

Comment: I was facing this issue when trying to format text returned from TinyMCE and this worked great for me!

Comment: Note: This solution can possibly corrupt other characters at the start/end of the string, as trim() will look for `\xC2` and `\xA0` individually! E.g. `echo trim('´test´', "\xC2\xA0");` will corrupt the first character by deleting its first byte!

Answer (score 9):

A little late to answer but hopefully might help someone else.  The most important while extracting content from html is to use [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) in php. Then all other string operations become a breeze.  Even foreign characters can be replaced by directly copy pasting characters from browser into the php code.  The following function replaces `&nbsp;` with a space.  Then all extra white spaces are replaced with a single white space using `preg_replace()`. Leading and trailing white spaces are removed in the end.

```
function clean($str)
{       
    $str = utf8_decode($str);
    $str = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$str);
    $str = trim($str);
    return $str;
}

$html = "1 $nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2 &nbsp; &nbsp; 3 &nbsp; 4";
$output = clean($html);
echo $output;
```

> 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 2):

if your string actually has "  ",

```
$str="1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2 &nbsp; &nbsp; 3 &nbsp; 4";
$s = str_replace("&nbsp; ","",$str);
print $s;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo str_replace ( "&nbsp;", "", "1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2 &nbsp; &nbsp; 3 &nbsp; 4" );
```

just remember you need to echo out the result of the str_replace and you alo dont need to worry about white spaces a the browser will only show one white space.

Answer (score 1):

This did the job for me:
preg_replace('~\x{00a0}~siu',' ',$content);