# PHP: parsing ascii string safely when running in multibyte mode

Tags: php, utf-8, multibyte

In my PHP config file I have

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');
```

To ensure UTF8 support. I have read that one should also use the multibyte string manipulation functions throughout if you have set these settings. I am currently altering a library which parses an excel file, and I need to split the one attribute value in the form N12 to determine the spreadsheet size. I know for a fact that the value cannot have values outside of ascii range. Do I need to use the multibyte string manipulation functions to parse the 12 out of N12 or can I use the normal ones. I am asking as I would like to keep the solution general and maybe submit the solution back to the library. If I need to use the correct function depending on whether current mode is utf8 or not, what is the best way to check for this?

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a pure superset of ASCII. If your functions can handle UTF-8, they by definition can also handle ASCII. The core PHP string functions mostly expect single-byte encodings, but that doesn't mean they won't work with other encodings; for example: [Multibyte trim in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067670/476).

So it depends on what exactly you're trying to do. Possibly core PHP string functions will already work fine regardless of encoding. If they do not, and your operation would break when using multi-byte strings, then you can use the appropriate MB function instead which by definition will also handle ASCII just fine when treating the input as UTF-8.