# remove white space inside tags without removing \n

Tags: php, regex

How to remove white spaces inside all tags, but, and this is important, **without removing \n**

In this example I have two type of tags. I am looking for something that could work in any text with any type of tags.

I have this:

```
$text ="<p> some text </p><h2> some text</h2>\n
<p>some text </p><h2>some text </h2>";
```

I want this:

```
<p>some text</p><h2>some text</h2>\n 
<p>some text</p><h2>some text</h2>
```

I tried:

```
$text = preg_replace ("/>\s+/", ">", $text);//remove space from start
$text = preg_replace ("/\s+</", "<", $text);//and end
echo $text;
```

The problem is that, it removes the \n too.

Comment: take a look at ltrim() and rtrim()

Comment: sorry misread the value of the variable

Comment: Did you try my answer? it removes spaces and tabulations but not line break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're closed, have a try with:

```
$text = preg_replace ("/> +/", ">", $text);//remove space from start
$text = preg_replace ("/ +</", "<", $text);//and end
```

If you want to remove also tabulations:

```
$text = preg_replace ("/>\h+/", ">", $text);//remove space from start
$text = preg_replace ("/\h+</", "<", $text);//and end
```

`\h` stands for horizontal space.

Comment: why put something together when there are functions available that will do the work for you

Comment: @RST: ltrim can't be used here because the spaces to removed are not at the begining of the string.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. Why do you think this solves the problem with \n ?

Comment: \n is a newline character. In this case that puts the $text in two lines

Comment: @segon: Sorry, I don't get you. What is the problem with `\n`? Did you try my answer? It gives the result you want.

Comment: Your answer gives: <p>some text</p><h2>some text</h2><p>some text</p><h2>some text</h2>. There is a \n after the first </h2>. You never see the \n but was there and it is removed

Comment: @segon: No it isn't, `\h` doesn't match `\n`

Comment: @Toto: Ok \h is good because it does not track newlines. But your code did not work. The right is :$text = preg_replace ("/>\h+/", ">", $text);
$text = preg_replace ("/\h+</", "<", $text);

Answer (score 1):

Here the < and > will be replaced
Try

```
$text = preg_replace ("/> /", ">", $text);//remove space from start
$text = preg_replace ("/ </", "<", $text);//and end
echo $text;
```

Comment: I do not understand your answer. Why do you think this solves the problem with \n ?

Comment: Now I see that your answer is good too. But you should explain that "/> /" tacks space but not \n And \s tracks spaces and \n. On the other site, add + would be good to remove if there is more than one space: /> +/

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you're looking for is the trim-function in php. There is no need to use regular expressions for that. Just call it with your string variable and it will work

Comment: exactly, that is what I said.

Comment: I didn't read your comment when I typed this. Nice to see that we're thinking alike

Comment: `trim()` works for multibyte strings too if [formatted correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066647/multibyte-trim-in-php) but it will remove `\n` which the author does not want

Comment: trim removes spaces at the beginning and end of all the text, not inside each tag

Answer (score 0):

To remove the space after/before a `<p>/</p>` tag you can use:

```
$text = str_replace('<p> ', '<p>', $text);
$text = str_replace(' </p>', '</p>', $text);
```

You could turn it in a function

```
function mytrim ( $text ) {
    $myChars = array('p', 'h2');

    foreach ( $myChars as $chr ) {
       $tag1 = '<' . $char . '> ';
       $tag2 = ' </' . $char . '>';
       $text = str_replace( $tag1, '<'. $char . '>', $text);
       $text = str_replace( $tag2, '</'. $char . '>', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

to use the function you would write

```
$text = mytrim($text);
```

Comment: ltrim can't be used here because the spaces to removed are not at the begining of the string

Comment: Yes, but it works only for `<p>` tag, not for `<h2>`

Comment: @Toto I think with this example anyone can easily extend it to whatever character removal they are looking for

Comment: turned it into a function that can be adjusted

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$text = str_replace(array('> ',' <'),array('>','<'),$text);
echo $text;
```

no use regular expressions.

Comment: How does it work if there are more than one space? or a tabulation?

Answer (score 0):

Use preg replace to match \r or \n or both and replace it with nothing.

```
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $text);
```

Removing indentation is concerned, that's just white space, which can be removed with php's function trim

```
$trimmed = trim($text);
```

Further, trim accepts a 2nd argument which you can pass in and have trimmed as well:

```
$trimmed = trim($text, '\t.');
```

Which for instance will trim the tab character.

this code useful for you

Comment: the question is remove white space WITHOUT removing \n

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could this be:

```
    <?php
    $text ="<p> some text </p><h2> some text</h2> 
<p>some text </p><h2>some text </h2>";

    $result = preg_replace_callback(
        '|>([^\r\n]*?)<|',
        function ($hit) {
            return '>'.trim($hit[1]).'<';
        },
        $text
    );

    echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($result) . '</pre>';  // for testing only

    ?>
```