# UTF-8 Error after trim(\xa0) in Eloquent accessor

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8, eloquent, trim

I'm trimming the first_name and the last_name of my users on a Model via Eloquent Accessors with the next helper:

```
function clean($string){
    return trim($string, " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xc2\xa0");
}
```

Then in the model:

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($firstname){
    return clean(ucwords(strtolower($firstname)));
}
public function getLastNameAttribute($lastname){
    return clean(ucwords(strtolower($lastname)));
}
```

A lot of names comes from an excel an has trailing spaces which can be removed trimming \xa0, but the problem comes when it tries to trim special characters, as (à).

I tried removing it and it doesn't fail, but well, it doesn't remove the trailing spaces.

I also tried making sure that the headers charset were set to utf-8

Any idea? Thanks.

**I just want the invisible spaces to be gone :/**

The error message:

```
InvalidArgumentException in JsonResponse.php line 69:
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`mb_strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) and [`mb_convert_case()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) instead of `strtolower()` and `ucwords()`.

Instead of `trim()` you could try this function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066647/multibyte-trim-in-php):

```
function mb_trim($str) {
    return preg_replace("/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/us", "", $str); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, tried, but it doesn't work either, it is the trim.

Comment: tried too, it doesn't remove all the trailing spaces   {
    "id": 95063,
    "first_name": "Xabier "} only when I add \xa0 to the trim it actually remove them all