# PHP trim unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, ascii, trim, html-entities

I am using the following function in PHP to trim some unwanted characters.

```
$inputString = "आनन्द मठ";
trim(html_entity_decode($inputString), " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xC2\xA0");
```

The above code is working fine for all cases but in one input string (`आनन्द मठ`) it is converting it to `आनन्द म�`. It has a unwanted �. Also happening for `परेटो- श्रेष्ठ` converted to `परेटो- श्रेष्�`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multibyte trim in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066647/multibyte-trim-in-php)

Comment: Why are you html decoding a string that is already decoded? Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
trim()
```

This function use iso-8859 encoding.

you must use UTF8 (Unicode) function. Try this function

```
function mb_trim($string, $charlist='\\\\s', $ltrim=true, $rtrim=true) 
{ 
    $both_ends = $ltrim && $rtrim; 

    $char_class_inner = preg_replace( 
        array( '/[\^\-\]\\\]/S', '/\\\{4}/S' ), 
        array( '\\\\\\0', '\\' ), 
        $charlist 
    ); 

    $work_horse = '[' . $char_class_inner . ']+'; 
    $ltrim && $left_pattern = '^' . $work_horse; 
    $rtrim && $right_pattern = $work_horse . '$'; 

    if($both_ends) 
    { 
        $pattern_middle = $left_pattern . '|' . $right_pattern; 
    } 
    elseif($ltrim) 
    { 
        $pattern_middle = $left_pattern; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $pattern_middle = $right_pattern; 
    } 

    return preg_replace("/$pattern_middle/usSD", '', $string) ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add http header in your php like

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

or put the encoding in a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```