# Why rtrim() trims character 'p' in PHP?

Tags: php, character-trimming

I want to remove `,&nbsp;` from the below string. Here what I have tried

```
$str = "3gp,&nbsp;";
echo rtrim($str,',&nbsp;');
```

But the output is `3g`

It always trims the character `p`.

I'm using PHP 7.1. Any idea on what's happening?

Edit: it trims 'n', 'b', 's', 'p'

Update: rtrim() removes characters from the last word. If I put a space between `p` and `,` i.e `$str = "3gp ,&nbsp;";` then it won't trim the character 'p'.

Comment: If you want to trim a phrase instead of characters, don’t use `rtrim()`, you can use `preg_replace()`:
`print preg_replace("/,&nbsp;$/", "", $str);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521051/trim-nbsp-with-php/12718471

Answer (score 1):

The [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function trims all characters in the `',&nbsp;'` string. This includes a `p`.

The second parameter represents characters. The [manual states](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

> You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the
> characters parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be
> stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.