# How to remove &nbsp; whenever it occurs between two characters?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find a way to remove any occurrences of a `&nbsp;` character when it occurs between two other characters.

Although I am not sure of the best way of doing this without it affecting the entire text body.

For example, I have the following text, and I want to remove the `&nbsp;` if it is between 2 opening curly braces `{{` or 2 closing curly braces `}}`:

```
<p>A element where the &nbsp; should be removed as it occurs between the desired characters: {{ $date_today&nbsp; }}</p>

<p>Another element which has a &nbsp; but should not be removed.</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim &nbsp; with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521051/trim-nbsp-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different options available py pure regex but I'd use a [callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for simplilcity.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\{\{.*?}}~s',
  function($m) { return str_ireplace('&nbsp;',"", $m[0]);
}, $str);
```

[See this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##TY/BTsMwEETv/opVFeEURYUzDa24ceydoshxFhyR2NZ6Q4Wi9NfDtrSot7E182Y2ujjP5Xb3ulMqS0zwDLqMmxfADnv0DAeHhMAO4c7XKa4huTB0DdQIhH34xgZMgpYhWDtQkn8@IPpzosHUkhisM2QsI6UnGEfIGsNYcWjMz4U5TeVD3Ch1avZBonTT31oHTjrMdUE98HWFmG@WrE4Uvf6/JBJ@VoSxMxYra7quNvYr18f9uB9X99tpOiZdKICPwVtug8@zfgmj0HggD8Ko2ks613/dulgsCsj6t8f35VpNIsUlSqF14fwQPc@/) or check out [the pattern explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cIvKF6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace to do this.

```
$string = "this is some random String &nbsp;
there is more on the next line &nbsp;
some more";

$newString = str_replace('r&nbsp;d','r d',$string);
echo $newString;
```

Here is some code to show how it would work.

Comment: This was my first approach although, as given from the question example is not suitable in this case as it would replace all instances of `&nbsp;`. I would like to replace when it occurs between 2 specific characters.

Comment: Ive, updated it to handle two specific characters. Were these characters variables or contstants?

Comment: Again this wouldn't really solve the problem. The data could have 0 or X amount of `&nbsp;` characters.